Error saving data: MongooseError: Operation `naafs.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
I have been having this error and it took me weeks. Hence, it is to request you to provide assistance to resolve this matter.
my Database connection( I am working on the backend of a mern-stack project) is:
const mongoose = require ('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/DawoodzaiMallDb', { 
    connectTimeoutMS: 200000  // Set a custom timeout (e.g., 20000 ms)
})
.then(() => console.log("The database is connected successfully"))
.catch(err => console.error('Failed to connect to the database', err));

and the server code is:
// server.js

const express = require('express');

// Create an Express application
const app = express();

// Middleware to handle JSON requests
app.use(express.json());

// Define a simple route to confirm the server is running
// app.get('/', (req, res) => {
//     res.send('Server is running!');
// });

naafRoute = require("./src/routes/postNaaf");

app.use("/naaf", naafRoute);

// Start the server
const PORT = 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});

Waiting for your helpful aid.

I don't see naafs.insertOne() called anywhere in that code?
